# FileNotFoundError \Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1\lib

Tags: python, pip, file-not-found

While trying to install PyNacl, i run into this error: `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v8.1\\lib'`

Which then leads to this: `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\HPZ420~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\PyNaCl\`

I've had no problems installing any other packages, and i've looked all over for solutions to no avail.

I've tried upgrading my setuptools, but that didnt help. Im open to any solution at this point.

Comment: How do you install PyNaCl? There are all possible binaries at PyPI so `pip install PyNaCl` should install a precompiled binary wheel, not install from sources.

Comment: I tried both py -m pip install PyNaCl in command prompt, and pip install PyNaCl in pycharm terminal. Both throw the same errors

Comment: Downgrade your version of Setuptools
Refer here this might be of a same problem [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38283599/error-while-installing-flask-in-virtualenv-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38283599/error-while-installing-flask-in-virtualenv-windows)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to download Microsoft SDK version 8.1 from this website. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive