# How to install Visual Studio 2015 PlatformSDK now?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, scrapy, pip

When I ran something (such as `pip install scrapy`) with python 3.7, I got a trouble with 
`error: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\PlatformSDK\\lib'`
and I found there is no `PlatformSDK` in my VS 14.0 at all.

(Update on 24 Jul 2018: I got another error `[WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v8.1\\lib'` when I ran `pip install scrapy` on another laptop, also Win 10 OS. I'm not sure whether my case is similar to [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50400571/filenotfounderror-microsoft-sdks-windows-v8-1-lib))

Then I got a `vs_community.exe` source from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44290672/how-to-download-visual-studio-community-edition-2015-not-2017) and installed `Web Developer Tools` and `Visual Studio Extensibility Tools Update 3` successfully, but still no `PlatformSDK`.

So how can I get this missing folder and its packages inside it?

Comment: VS2005 was the last VS version that still deployed the Windows SDK into the PlatformSDK subdirectory.  It has its own install directory now.  Versions 6.x and 7.x are normally in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows, versions 8.0 and up are in c:\program files (x86)\windows kits.  What you need to do to update the "I ran something" code to tell it about the other directory, or what version you need, is not obvious from the question.  Version 7.1 is usually the safe bet.

Comment: @HansPassant Hi, I have updated my post. Actually the error occurred on pip install command, so it is hard for me to change the source code to meet the new directory.

Comment: Then you'd better change to the tags on the question to find somebody that does, at least [python] and [pip] I'd say.  And name the package you are trying to use.

Comment: @HansPassant ok I will do it. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried installing scrapy as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/32545749/939364 ?

Answer (score 3):

Once I had a problem installing another Python program (QARK) that required Windows Visual C++. In fact in cmd / PowerShell I was told that a required version was missing.
So I followed what was written on [THIS](https://www.scivision.dev/python-windows-visual-c-14-required/) site, so I didn't have this problem anymore (I also rebooted, for safety):

> 1. Install using any ONE of these choices:
>
>    - Microsoft [Build Tools for Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16)
>    - Alternative link to Microsoft [Build Tools for Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019).
>    - Offline installer: [vs_buildtools.exe](https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vs_buildtools.exe)
> 2. Select: Workloads → C++ build tools.
> 3. Install options: select only the “Windows 10 SDK” (assuming the computer is Windows 10). Optionally, if you want to use MSVC cl.exe C/C++ compiler from the command line, additionally select the C++ build tools, which takes an additional 2 GB disk space.

After that I didn't have any problems running it.
I hope I have been helpful!